# How do I access to a variable outside of loop in dart?

Tags: loops, for-loop, flutter, variables, dart

I programmed a little TicTacToe AI in which I declare the 'bestMove' inside the loop, but can't access it outside of it.

```
void computerMove() {
    int _currentMove;
    int _currentScore = 0;
    int _bestMove; // here i initialize it
    int _bestScore = 0;
    List<String> boardWithMove = List.from(_board);
    if (!isWin() && !isDraw()) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        // checks all first move possibilities
        if (_board[i] == null) {
          if (_computerIsX) {
            boardWithMove[i] = 'X';
            _currentMove = i;
            print(_currentMove);
            print('computer thinking');
          }
          // Try's all possibilities for the initial move
          for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
            if (boardWithMove[i] == null) {
              if (_computerTurn && _computerIsX) {
                boardWithMove[i] = 'X';
                _computerTurn = false;
                if (isWin()) {
                  _currentScore++;
                }
              } else if (!_computerTurn && _computerIsX) {
                boardWithMove[i] = 'O';
                _computerTurn = true;
                if (isWin()) {
                  _currentScore--;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          // safes the best move with best results
          if (_currentScore > _bestScore) {
            _bestScore = _currentScore;
            _bestMove = _currentMove; // here i change it
            print(_bestMove);
          }
        }
      }
      // sets the best output
      if (_computerIsX) {
        print(_bestMove); // returns null
        _board[_bestMove] = 'X'; // here I want to use it
      } else if (!_computerIsX) {
        _board[_bestMove] = 'O';
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tried having a getter and setter method for the variable.

Consol prints this:

I/flutter ( 6179): 1
I/flutter ( 6179): computer thinking
I/flutter ( 6179): 2
...

I/flutter ( 6179): computer thinking
I/flutter ( 6179): 7
I/flutter ( 6179): computer thinking
I/flutter ( 6179): 8
I/flutter ( 6179): computer thinking
I/flutter ( 6179): null

Comment: What happens if you just call _bestMove = "X" ?

Comment: I'm afraid that would not help, cause _bestMove is an integer which should save the best position (from 0 for the first postion to 8 the last position) to put the 'X' in :/

Comment: I see, sorry I misread your code. Does that print(_bestMove) work outside the loop? And try putting some print(_bestMove) inside your loop, make sure it actually gets set.

Answer (score 0):

The `bestMove` variable is being overwritten somehow in the logic.

If your board contains 8 values, your loop indexes will be from 0 to 7 as List indexing is zero based.

Scope wise `bestMove` variable is available to you at every point in `computerMove()`.

Please remove the underscore prefixes `_` as local variables don't have private scope.
It applies only to library/class level.